# Unable to import a module in atom on Mac

Tags: python, import, module

When I try to `import` a module named `my_module.py` into the module i am working on named `LEARNING PYTHON.py`, I get an error message saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/folders/tn/g0fq2j9d1hs6gss6db_4czwm0000gn/T/atom_script_tempfiles/2021710-52462-1bl6rr4.wrni", line 16, in <module>
    import my_module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_module'
```

I am running the latest version of python and pip on my Mac and as far as i know, both modules are in the same directory. For `my_module.py` and `LEARNING PYTHON.py`, when I print the directory using:

```
import os

print(os.getcwd())
```

the following is displayed for both modules:

```
/Users/dylanneal/Documents
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and how I can `import my_module` in my `LEARNING PYTHON.py` file?

Comment: Hello, welcome to stack overflow.

Can we get the contents of the two files?

Comment: What matters is whether `my_module.py` and `LEARNING PYTHON.py` in the same folder, not what the the cwd (current working directory) is.

Comment: You'll probably want to check whether your module file is in `sys.path`,  via: `import sys; print(sys.path)`. If the directory containing the module is not in sys.path, it will not be imported